# Combination of multinomial logit model and logit model

Tags: stata, multinomial-distribution, logit

I want to analyze the determinants of credit constraints of a firm. I have information for both formal and informal credit. I have 6 categories of credit-constraint statuses of a firm for formal credit, while I only have 2 categories for informal credit. As credit constraint status is determined simultaneously, and formal and informal credit market are interrelated, I want to estimate the determinants of credit constraints for formal and informal credit market at the same time. Bivariate logit/probit model may be too simplistic. Is there extension of bivariate logit model or some kind of multivariate multinomial logit model in Stata?  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at a latent class model? Basically, each decision-maker has an estimated probability of being given one of several choice sets. The coefficients for each set, and the coefficients for the latent class model, are all determined simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure but my dependent variables are not latent variables, and the aim is to identify the determinants of credit-constraint statuses (defined by two variables - one is binary, and the other is 6 category variables). Sorry if my explanation is not clear.